# ¿Por qué mi arreglo de punteros a estructuras no guarda información en el primer elemento?

Tags: array, c, funciones, estructuras

Cuando compilo el programa, la primera opción la acepta hasta 7 personas que es el máximo. Sin embargo, cuando elijo la segunda opción me muestra el contenido de los demás elementos del arreglo 1-6, excepto el 0 (`Datos[0]`), y no se por qué es el único elemento que no me muestra su contenido que he ingresado con anterioridad.

He pensado que es la función `malloc`, pero el problema no reside ahí. He intentado que el programa me muestre el contenido de `Datos[0]` después de ingresar la opción 1, y que al inicio del menú se muestre. Esto solo pasa una vez, pues cuando ingreso a otra persona, el contenido de `Datos[0]` desaparece y su contenido es aleatorio.

Me ayudarían si me explican la lógica de mi problema y su posible solución.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Persona{
    char nombre[30];
    char apellidopat[10];
    short edad;
    char genero;
    char clave[30];
};
void fulldata(struct Persona*Datos[], short n_persona);
void muestra(struct Persona*Datos[],short n_persona);
int main(){
    struct Persona *Datos[7];
    printf("--Base de Datos Personas--\n");
    short opcion, n_persona=0;
    do{
    printf("\n");
    puts("Menu: ");
    puts("1- Ingresar datos de persona");
    puts("2-Mostrar informacion de persona");
    puts("3-Mostrar claves de personas");
    puts("4-Mostrar claves de todos lo hombres");
    puts("5-Mostrar clave de todas las mujeres");
    puts("6-Mostrar clave en base a la edad");
    puts("7-Salir");
    printf("\nEleja una opcion: ");
    scanf("%i",&opcion);
    fflush(stdin);
    switch (opcion){
    case 1:
            if(n_persona<7){
                fulldata(Datos,n_persona);
                n_persona++;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nNumero maximo de personas en la base de datos\n");
            }
        break;
    case 2:
            muestra(Datos,n_persona);
        break;
    
    default: printf("\nIngrese una opcion valida\n");
        break;
    }
    }while(opcion!=7);
    return 0;
}
void fulldata(struct Persona*Datos[], short n_persona){
    Datos[n_persona]=(struct Persona*)malloc(sizeof(struct Persona));
    printf("\nPersona %d",n_persona+1);
    printf("\nNombre: ");
    scanf("%s",&Datos[n_persona]->nombre);
    printf("Apellido Paterno: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&Datos[n_persona]->apellidopat);
    printf("Edad: ");
    scanf("%i",&Datos[n_persona]->edad);
    printf("Genero (H/M): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&Datos[n_persona]->genero);
    Datos[n_persona]->genero=toupper(Datos[n_persona]->genero);
}
void muestra(struct Persona*Datos[],short n_persona){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n_persona;i++){
        printf("\n->Persona %d\n",i+1);
        printf("Nombre: %s",Datos[i]->nombre);
        printf("\nApellido Paterno: %s",Datos[i]->apellidopat);
        printf("\nEdad: %i",Datos[i]->edad);
        printf("\nGenero: %c",Datos[i]->genero);
    }
}
```

Comment: No tengo clara la causa, hace mucho que no juego con punteros. Pero, ¿puedes hacer que no se pase el *Persona *Datos[]* por parámetro? Por ejemplo, haz el *malloc* fuera del método y solo pasa por parámetro el elemento, o *fulldata* no recibe parámetros y hace el *malloc* y devuelve el *Persona**. No solo puede ser que esté relacionado con ese parámetro, también es más elegante (*fulldata* no necesita saber que guardas los datos en un array para funcionar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo raro es que te llegue a mostrar los datos de alguno. Me explico, fíjate en la siguiente línea:

```
scanf("%s",&Datos[n_persona]->nombre);
```

`scanf` necesita un puntero a la variable a actualizar, vale, pero es que resulta que `nombre` es de tipo `char[]`, es decir, implícitamente ya es un puntero, luego no necesitas usar `&`. La lectura de cadenas se hace así:

```
scanf("%s",Datos[n_persona]->nombre);
```

Luego tienes otro problema en la lectura del género:

```
scanf("%c",&Datos[n_persona]->genero);
```

El problema es que antes de leer este caracter, has leído un entero. Una lectura de números o de cadenas con `scanf` deja el separador que sigue al dato leído en el buffer de entrada. Es decir, en tu caso tendrías algo así en la `stdin`

```
\nH
```

Es decir, tendrías el salto de línea y a ti no te interesa leer ese salto de línea sino lo que le sigue. Una forma facil de descartar este caracter es añadir un espacio antes del `%c`. De esta forma `scanf` sabe que debe descartar los delimitadores que encuentre y leer únicamente el primer caracter que no sea un delimitador.

```
scanf(" %c",&Datos[n_persona]->genero);
```

Con estos cambios a mi el programa me funciona correctamente